# Incorect password when trying to login with data from cookies

Tags: php, html, authentication, cookies

I'm trying to implement "Remember me" and I want to login the user  from cookies but if I use the variable $password it says `Incorrect email and/or password!` . I've tried to directly save the password from the form and it works.

This is how I implemented the login:

authenticate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'webproject1';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['pwd']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the email and password fields!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the email is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
        if (password_verify($_POST['pwd'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has logged-in!
            // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            if($_POST['remember'] == 1 || $_POST['remember'] == "on") {
                setcookie('name', $_POST['email'],time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                setcookie('pwd', $password,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
            }
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            // Incorrect password
            echo 'Incorrect email and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        // Incorrect email
        echo 'Incorrect email and/or password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

and this is index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'webproject1';
$name = $_COOKIE["name"];
$pwd = $_COOKIE["pwd"];
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?')) {
      // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the email is a string so we use "s"
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
      $stmt->execute();
      // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
      $stmt->store_result();
    
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
            $stmt->fetch();
            // Account exists, now we verify the password.
            // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
            if (password_verify($pwd, $password)) {
                // Verification success! User has logged-in!
                // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                if($_POST['remember'] == 1 || $_POST['remember'] == "on") {
                    setcookie('name', $name,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                    setcookie('pwd', $password,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                }
                header('Location: php/home.php');
            } else {
                // Incorrect password
                echo 'Incorrect email and/or password!';
            }
        } else {
            // Incorrect email
            echo 'Incorrect email and/or password!';
        }
      $stmt->close();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head >
  <title>Web project 1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form action="php/authenticate.php" method = "post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run this code it will show: `Incorrect email and/or password!` but when I change  `setcookie('pwd', $password,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`  with `$_POST['pwd']` the user is logged in fine. But I don't like this because the password can be seen inside the cookie.
I want that so after closing the browser and if "Remember me" was selected, I want the user to be redirected to home instead of login page

Comment: your form does not set cookies, it sends `$_POST["pwd"]`

Comment: After logging successfully I set the cookies: `setcookie('pwd', $password,time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`

Comment: You do not read the user's entries

Comment: Because when I access index.php, I want to redirect the user to home.php if the cookies with email/password exist without waiting for input

Comment: Setting the clear text password i a COOKIE is a very bad idea...especially on the frontend... instead "Remember me" should extend the session, and not do any re-auth.

Comment: How can I extend the session? So that after closing the browser the user is still logged in?